# Непонятное поведение массива при заполнении

Tags: c, g++

Осваиваю С, "среда" разработки Sublime Text 2 + GCC. Для знакомства с основами решил написать программу, заполняющую квадрат определённого размера числами по порядку (в данном случае квадрат 8 на 8, а числа от 1 до 64) ходом коня.

Проблема в том, что время от времени возникает ситуация, когда очередной элемент записывается в матрицу либо по "прямой" либо ходом коня, увеличенным в несколько раз.

При проверке каждой функции отдельно, все работают правильно. Во всяком случае мне так кажется.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

const short int s=8;

void PrintResult(short int [s][s]);
int Nullify(short int [s][s]);
bool CheckStep(short int *, short int *, short int [s][s], short int *);
short int MakeStep(short int *, short int *, short int [s][s], short int *, short int *);
short int GetMaxElemVal(short int [s][s]);
short int GetMaxElemX(short int [s][s], short int *);
short int GetMaxElemY(short int [s][s], short int *);
short int GetNewDirection(void);


int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); // that needs for "true" random

    short int field [s][s];
    short int step; // current number to put [1..s*s]  
    short int xCoord=0; // start    |   coordinats
    short int yCoord=0; //  |   position    |

    short int dir=0;
    short int failCount=0; // on 8-count set fail "true"

    while(step<s*s)
    {
        Nullify(field);
        step=1;
        xCoord=0+rand()%(s-1);
        yCoord=0+rand()%(s-1);
        field[xCoord][yCoord]=step;
        failCount=0;
        while(failCount<8 & step<s*s)
        {
            dir=GetNewDirection();
            if(CheckStep(&xCoord,&yCoord,field,&dir)==true)
            {
                step++;
                MakeStep(&xCoord,&yCoord,field,&dir,&step);
                failCount=0;
                xCoord=GetMaxElemX(field, &step);
                yCoord=GetMaxElemY(field, &step);
            }
            else
                failCount++;
            if(failCount==8)
                PrintResult(field);     
        }
        printf("this time maximum element is %d. \n Press any key to start again. \n",step);
        (void)getchar();
    }
    printf("\n\n the end. Press Any key to exit."); 
    (void)getchar();

    exit(0);
}
```

Листинг используемых функций.

```
void PrintResult(short int array[s][s]) // print matrix to screen
{//ok
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
            printf("%2d|",array[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int Nullify(short int array[s][s]) // fill matrix with zeroes
{//ok
    short int nullCount=0;

    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            array[i][j]=0;
            nullCount++;
        }

    return nullCount;
}

bool CheckStep(short int *currentXcoord, short int *currentYcoord, short int array[s][s], short int *direction) // check selected position 
{//ok?
    bool res=false;
    switch(*direction)
    {
        case 1: // up-up-right
            {
                if(*currentXcoord+1<s & *currentYcoord+2<s & array[*currentXcoord+1][*currentYcoord+2]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 2: // up-right-right
            {
                if(*currentXcoord+2<s & *currentYcoord+1<s & array[*currentXcoord+2][*currentYcoord+1]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 3: // down-right-right
            {
                if(*currentXcoord+2<s & *currentYcoord-1>0 & array[*currentXcoord+2][*currentYcoord-1]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 4: // down-down-right
            {
                if(*currentXcoord+1<s & *currentYcoord-2>0 & array[*currentXcoord+1][*currentYcoord-2]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 5: // down-down-left
            {
                if(*currentXcoord-1>0 & *currentYcoord-2>0 & array[*currentXcoord-1][*currentYcoord-2]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            }
        case 6: // down-left-left
            {
                if(*currentXcoord-2>0 & *currentYcoord-1>0 & array[*currentXcoord-2][*currentYcoord-1]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 7: // up-left-left
            {
                if(*currentXcoord-2>0 & *currentYcoord+1<s & array[*currentXcoord-2][*currentYcoord+1]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        case 8: // up-up-left
            {
                if(*currentXcoord-1>0 & *currentYcoord+2<s & array[*currentXcoord-1][*currentYcoord+2]==0)
                    res=true;
                else
                    res=false;
            } break;
        default:res=false;
    }

    return res;
}

short int MakeStep(short int *currentXcoord, short int *currentYcoord, short int array[s][s], short int *direction, short int *value) // next step and inc
{//ok
    switch(*direction)
    {
        // up-up-right
        case 1: array[*currentXcoord+1][*currentYcoord+2]=*value; break;
        // up-right-right
        case 2: array[*currentXcoord+2][*currentYcoord+1]=*value; break;
        // down-right-right
        case 3: array[*currentXcoord+2][*currentYcoord-1]=*value; break;
        // down-down-right
        case 4: array[*currentXcoord+1][*currentYcoord-2]=*value; break;
        // down-down-left
        case 5: array[*currentXcoord-1][*currentYcoord-2]=*value; break;
        // down-left-left
        case 6: array[*currentXcoord-2][*currentYcoord-1]=*value; break;
        // up-left-left
        case 7: array[*currentXcoord-2][*currentYcoord+1]=*value; break;
        // up-up-left
        case 8: array[*currentXcoord-1][*currentYcoord+2]=*value; break;
        default:;
    }
    return *value;
}

short int GetMaxElemX(short int array[s][s], short int *maxelem)
{//ok
    short int x=-1;

    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
            if(*maxelem==array[i][j])
                x=j;

    return x;
}

short int GetMaxElemY(short int array[s][s], short int *maxelem)
{//ok
    short int y=-1;

    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
            if(*maxelem==array[i][j])
                y=i;

    return y;
}

short int GetNewDirection(void)
{//ok
    return 1+rand()%8; // for now
}
```

Comment: А почему в ваших условиях "if(*currentXcoord+1<s & *currentYcoord+2<s &..." побитовое и, а не логическое? Так за пределы массива легко вылезти

Comment: @Unick , Изучаю язык по книге, в ней пока не было описано различия между & и &&, равно как и между | и ||, однако принял к сведенью и исправил. Помимо этого добавил недостающий break, однако поведение программы осталось прежним.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте добавил какую-то проверку, если программа хочет сделать некорректный ход, то выдавать ошибку и смотреть на каком шаге это вышло.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, проблема в том, что у вас в case 5:

```
case 5: // down-down-left
{
    if(*currentXcoord-1>0 & *currentYcoord-2>0 & array[*currentXcoord-1][*currentYcoord-2]==0)
        res=true;
    else
        res=false;
}
```

Пропущен `break;` в конце.

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Проблема была в поиске координат последнего шага в матрице. 
Последний шаг стоит на позиции [х][у], а его координаты подавались как [у][х].